# Estimate degrees of freedom in linear mixed model contrasts on large datasets using R

Tags: r, bigdata, lsmeans

I have a large dataset that I have been analysing using a linear mixed model (~600000 observations). Usually, I estimate the least-square means and do pairwise contrasts using the **lsmeans** from **lsmeans** package. I also use the estimates of the degrees of freedom to test for the significance of each contrast, using  a *t* statistic, as many times I have actually a quite low number. However, I cannot apply **lsmeans** on my dataset. Below I show example, in which I simulate datasets of different sizes.

```
library(lme4)
library(lsmeans)

SmallData<-data.frame(R=rnorm(10000,23,4),A=sample(letters[1:2],10000,replace=TRUE),B=sample(letters[11:23],10000,replace=TRUE))
MediumData<-data.frame(R=rnorm(100000,23,4),A=sample(letters[1:2],100000,replace=TRUE),B=sample(letters[11:23],10000,replace=TRUE))
LargeData<-data.frame(R=rnorm(600000,23,4),A=sample(letters[1:2],600000,replace=TRUE),B=sample(letters[11:23],10000,replace=TRUE))

modelSmall<-lmer(R ~ B + (1|A),data=SmallData)
modelMedium<-lmer(R ~ B + (1|A),data=MediumData)
modelLarge<-lmer(R ~ B + (1|A),data=LargeData)

Small.lsm<-lsmeans(modelSmall,~B)

Small.lsm

$lsmeans
 B   lsmean         SE    df lower.CL upper.CL
 k 22.99691 0.05649338 74.85 22.88436 23.10945
 l 22.99451 0.05656906 75.68 22.88184 23.10719

Results are averaged over the levels of: C
Confidence level used: 0.95

$contrasts
 contrast    estimate        SE      df t.ratio p.value
 k - l    0.002397375 0.0799509 9992.92    0.03  0.9761

Results are averaged over the levels of: C

Small.lsm<-lsmeans(modelSmall,pairwise~B|C)

Small.lsm

$lsmeans
C = m:
 B   lsmean         SE     df lower.CL upper.CL
 k 22.98629 0.07980879 294.10 22.82923 23.14336
 l 23.01980 0.07946976 286.64 22.86338 23.17621

C = n:
 B   lsmean         SE     df lower.CL upper.CL
 k 23.00752 0.07996624 292.46 22.85014 23.16490
 l 22.96923 0.08053307 304.92 22.81075 23.12770

Confidence level used: 0.95

$contrasts
C = m:
 contrast    estimate        SE      df t.ratio p.value
 k - l    -0.03350181 0.1126268 9996.00  -0.297  0.7661

C = n:
 contrast    estimate        SE      df t.ratio p.value
 k - l     0.03829656 0.1134942 9994.74   0.337  0.7358


Medium.lsm<-lsmeans(modelMedium,pairwise~B|C) # Memory overload (~70 Gb RAM)

Large.lsm<-lsmeans(modelLarge,pairwise~B|C)

Large.lsm<-lsmeans(modelLarge,pairwise~B|C)
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x7f9de00ff000, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: t(ZZ) %*% EE %*% ZZ
 2: t(ZZ) %*% EE %*% ZZ
 3: .get_SigmaG(object, details)
 4: get_SigmaG.lmerMod(object, details)
 5: get_SigmaG(object, details)
 6: pbkrtest::vcovAdj.lmerMod(object, 0)
 7: lsm.basis.merMod(object, trms, xlev, grid, ...)
 8: lsm.basis(object, trms, xlev, grid, ...)
 9: ref.grid(object = <S4 object of class "lmerMod">, by = "C", contr = "pairwise")
10: do.call("ref.grid", rgargs)
11: lsmeans.default(object, specs, ...)
12: lsmeans.character.default(object, specs = all.vars(specs[-2]),     by = by, contr = contr.spec, ...)
13: lsmeans.character(object, specs = all.vars(specs[-2]), by = by,     contr = contr.spec, ...)
14: lsmeans(object, specs = all.vars(specs[-2]), by = by, contr = contr.spec,     ...)
15: lsmeans.formula(modelLarge, pairwise ~ B | C)
16: lsmeans(modelLarge, pairwise ~ B | C)
```

I have also tried **lmerTest** package and used **difflsmeans** function and it also crashed. I can get the mean estimates using general linear hypothesis testing - **glht** from **multcomp** package -, but this procedure does not estimate degrees of freedom of the specific contrasts. Do you know of any alternative to these procedures that is applicable to large datasets?

Thank you very, very much.

Comment: How are you calculating degrees of freedom? Welch-Satterthwaite?

Comment: Code that produces segfaults should be sent to the package maintainer.

Comment: I think the problem is in the degrees-of-freedom and adjusted covariance calculation. It is complex and you have a huge dataset. Try doing `lsm.options(disable.pbkrtest = TRUE)`, then it will skip those calculations.

Comment: Can you give an example/order of magnitude of what you mean when you say you have "actually a quite low number" of degrees of freedom?  If you're testing at the alpha=0.05 level, it doesn't take much before you don't really need to worry about this.  e.g. `qt(0.975,50)` is 2 rather than 1.96 ... your "small" example above has df=75 ...

Comment: Disabling the 'pbkrtest' actually allows 'lsmeans' to run on my dataset, but, as expected, it does not estimate the degrees of freedom, which is exactly my main objective.
In my dataset, for some reason, when I use 'lme' and estimate the degrees of freedom of one of the major factors, I sometimes obtain 2 to 3, so I guess some of the contrasts might have this low number of d.f. as well...

Comment: @Alex: Degrees of freedom are calculated using Kenward-Roger approximation.

Comment: @user2958580 can't you just calculate the DF manually? Obviously, this isn't an answer to your question; but it may solve your problem.

Comment: @Alex I do not know how to do it... from what I read in Halekoh and Hojsgaard 2014... nor how long I will take to do it. It might take quite long, I would take it as a last resourt. Unless you have an idea on how to do it quickly and I would greatly appreciate!

Comment: I don't unfortunately. I am not familiar with KR deg. freedom. This [link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108161/satterthwaite-vs-kenward-roger-approximations-for-the-df-in-mixed-effects-models) has some additional detail--including article links. One of those articles may have some additional detail or the coding... Though as @BenBolker notes, it may not matter for your sample sizes.